# how to modify parent class variable with the child class and use in another child class in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

```
class A(object):
    __A = None
    def get_a(self):
        return self.__A
    def set_a(self, value):
        self.__A = value

class B(A):
    def method_b(self, value):
        self.set_a(value)

class C(A):
    def method_c(self)
         self.get_a()
```

Someone can to explain me how can i to catch installed value in method_b inside my 'C' class method?

P.S. In this variant i just getting nothing.

Comment: `def method_b(self, 13):` - this is invalid syntax.

Comment: 1. You can't use numbers in functions definition. 2. Why would you get 13 in class C where you only set it in class B while class C has nothing to do with class B?

Comment: You should try to create an [mcve] of what you're trying to achieve by doing this

Comment: Sorry my bad. I slightly changed the code, let's say it's dynamic value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python isn't Java; you don't need setters & getters here: just access the attributes directly.

There are three problems with your code.

1. `C.method_c()` has no `return` statement, so it returns `None`.
2. You are using `__` [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) when that's exactly what you *don't* want.
3. In `A.set_a()` you want to set a class attribute, but your assignment instead creates an instance attribute which shadows the class attribute.

Here's a repaired version.

```
class A(object):
    _A = 'nothing'
    def get_a(self):
        return self._A
    def set_a(self, value):
        A._A = value

class B(A):
    def method_b(self, value):
        self.set_a(value)

class C(A):
    def method_c(self):
        return self.get_a()

b = B()
c = C()
print(c.method_c())
b.method_b(13)
print(c.method_c())
```

**output**

```
nothing
13
```

---

Here's a slightly more Pythonic version:

```
class A(object):
    _A = 'nothing'

class B(A):
    def method_b(self, value):
        A._A = value

class C(A):
    pass

b = B()
c = C()
print(c._A)
b.method_b(13)
print(c._A)
```